# Why are my drop downs not working in ie7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

If you view this page: http://www.sussexjewelers.com/product_search.php?cid=69

The drop down menus (horizontal green bar) do not drop down in ie7. They do drop down in ie6, firefox, and chrome. Also if you view the homepage the same drop downs DO work in ie7. I cannot figure out why they are not working on this page in ie7. They are pure CSS drop down menus.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI doesn't work in IE7 or IE8

Comment: Your site is also rendered in IE5 Quirks mode because your DOCTYPE is NOT the first tag on the page... all the extra script/style info is forcing your site into Quirks Mode instead of Standards Mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of style and script tags before the actual HTML document. Those should be in the head tag of the page.

The doctype tag has to be the first tag in the source, otherwise IE will render the page in quirks mode. Other browsers may also render it in quirks mode, but it makes a lot more difference for IE. One big difference is that the [box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) is handled incorrectly.

Once you get the basic structure of the code correct, you should [validate the html](http://validator.w3.org/), and [the css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to see if there are more problems in the code. I can see right away that you have an HTML doctype but you are using XHTML tags in the code.

If the menues still doesn't work after cleaning up the code, I would guess that it's a problem with the z-index so that the menues show up but is hidden behind the main content. IE doesn't handle z-index correctly for elements that has layout.

Comment: Here's a validation link for you 314 errors should give you something to work on...   http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sussexjewelers.com%2Fproduct_search.php%3Fcid%3D69

Answer (score 2):

Your `<style>` and `<script>` tags should be inside your `<head>` tag, not outside your `<html>` tag.

Also add a DOCTYPE

XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

HTML 4

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

TonyF is right.  In the future, try running this in your URL bar to see if you're actually in Standards Mode (CSS1Compat) vs Quirks Mode (BackCompat):

```
javascript:alert(document.compatMode)
```

I have that in a bookmarklet in IE.